# 2 GPUs but use only one for load

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, multiple-monitors

I have two GPUs installed : AMD Radeon HD7870 and Nvidia Geforce 8400 GS

So I have the Geforce 8400 GS for a third Monitor and also for the S-VIDEO output, but it has no power at all so I only want to use it as connection for more ports.

If I start an DirectX11 Game on the GF8400 GS it won't start of course, but if I open it on Windowed mode with the HD7870 and drag it over to the GF8400 GS it works just fine, not with 100% power but enough.

Is there a way to completely use the HD7870 to do everything and use the GF8400 GS only to connect more Monitors?

Thanks for Helping

Comment: The only way to handle multiple GPUs with DX11, is SLI and Crossfire, only DX12 on the current build of Windows 10 supports multi-GPU from multiple venders

Comment: Oh okay but still how then is it possible to run things in windowed mode on the GF8400, while the HD7870 takes the load?

Im not saying I want both GPUs to render one Game I just want to use the HD7870 for Rendering on a Monitor which is connected to the GF8400GS which works in window mode for Games.

Comment: It seems it only does that when I run DirectX11 Games. I tried this with Resident Evil 7 in High settings which the Card could never be capable to run smoothly. FPS drop from 60 to 40 though, which is not a problem. The HD7870 has about 42x the Power of the GF, so it must be the HD7870 doing it

Comment: What you want isn’t possible with DX11.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isnt very clear.  However, to answer one of your questions, no the AMD cannot control the NVidia card.  Not only are completely independent of each other, they are from different manufacturers and use different drivers.  This might be your problem.  While you didnt list your operating system, I am assuming Windows.  Mixing graphics cards isnt recommended, as their are driver issues.  You would most likely get much better performance removing one of the video cards and replacing it with one from the same brand.  If all you want is more monitor connections, then you can easily find low end cards with multiple display outputs on the web for cheap.

Comment: Yeah sorry for not having the clearest question, english is not my native language but in native sites I don't really get help so I tried here.

Of course they are different and they work normally independent of each other yeah, but the thing I tried with starting on the HD7870 in Window mode and dragging it over to the GF8400 GS, shows me that it may be possible because the GF8400 GS would never be capeable of DirectX11 so it must be using the HD7870 for this.

Comment: @Geschnallt Its ok.  :)  That NVidia card is *ancient* just get a cheap AMD card from Amazon or some other retailer.  That *should* solve your problems.

Comment: I think generally I would run into the same Problem. I even have an old AMD card a HD 6450 BUT I need to use the Legacy drivers from 2015 for it. Which would be no problem but then the HD7870 also uses the old drivers from 2015 which gives me a bad performance for the Main card :/

I can still try it at least with the old drivers to see if its possible, would it then use Crossfire to let the HD7870 do ALL the work?

Comment: @Geschnallt I dont understand why you would think that.  Just get a card that doesnt require extra power from the PSU.  https://www.amazon.com/Genuine-Dell-Full-Height-Graphics-Numbers/dp/B074LBT3QK/ref=sr_1_1?s=pc&ie=UTF8&qid=1523130267&sr=1-1&keywords=amd+graphics+card

Comment: If I would use an old AMD Card this is the Problem I will run into.
I did before so I switched to the Nvidia
https://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop/legacy?product=legacy3&os=Windows%207%20-%2064